# Craft ordering tags by 'name'

Tags: cache, tags, error, tasks

I've got a problem with some tasks. Craft tells me 'Deleting Stale Template Caches Failed' multiple times.

When I look in the Deprecated Warnings, it tells me two things:

- Ordering tags by ‘name’ has been deprecated. Order by ‘title’ instead.
- The Tag ‘name’ property has been deprecated. Use ‘title’ instead.

I don't know if this will fix my task errors, but it would be nice to solve this problem as well.

This warning is strange to me because I don't ordering my tags by name, I order them by title:

```
 <section class="overview-search__filter">
    <div class="overview-search__filter-item activity">
        <select class="multiselect multiselect-activitytype" multiple="multiple" data-search-filter="activityType" name="activityType">
            {% for tag in tags.order('title') %}
                {% set selected = (filters['activityType'] is defined and tag.title in filters['activityType']) ? 'selected': ''  %}
                <option value="{{ tag.title }}" {{ selected }}>{{ tag.title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="overview-search__filter-item activity">
        <select class="multiselect multiselect-place" multiple="multiple" data-search-filter="activityLocation" name="activityLocation">
            {% for location in locations.order('title') %}
                {% set selected = (filters['activityLocation'] is defined and location.title in filters['activityLocation']) ? 'selected': '' %}
                <option value="{{ location.title }}" {{ selected }}>{{ location.title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll just throw out the support article for debugging stuck tasks: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem sounds like it might be a permissions issue. Have you made sure you've got the right permissions on the `/craft/storage` folder? More details can be found here in the docs:

[Step 2: Set the permissions](https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-2-set-the-permissions)

Possibly related to the above, did you originally use `name` and then updated it to `title` at a later time? One possible reason for your deprecated messages might be the template is cached with the old `name` value. Sorting out the above should at least enable you to clear the cache, using the `Clear caches` button in the `Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fixed the first problem, it was a memory issue because I was using too many 'cache' blocks.

The problem related to the title and filter is still not solved. In the past I did used 'name'. After I changed it to 'title' I deleted my cache, but the problem still occurs. I've deleting my cache a couple times but without succes. I also deleted my 'cache'  directory in my storage.

Comment: No worries. If you visit the page in question now, do you still get deprecation errors? Only these may just be left over from when you originally had `name` in there.

Comment: I just noticed you've got an array in there called `filters`, how is that getting populated? Only I don't see it in your example code. If that's in another file maybe you've accidentally left a reference to `name` in there?

Comment: The population of filters has no ref to name. I find it strange that the deprecation errors could be left over from the past. Is there a way to delete this 'cached' error?

Comment: When I said they could be left over, I just meant unless you clear the deprecation errors, they will remain in the list. Take a look at the errors in the Control Panel `/admin/utils/deprecationerrors`. If the date in the `last occurrence` column is in the past then it's no longer a problem you need to worry about. If that is the case then you can just clear the deprecation errors individually by clicking the little `Delete` button on the right. Or if you want to get rid of all of them just click the `Clear All` button.